# Android browser share menu item in React SPA

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, single-page-application

I am building a mobile SPA using the React Router. Now the Chrome browser menu has the default Share feature which lets us share the URL in the browser. The issue is that the Share feature only share the URL while landing on the SPA but doesn't update it when navigating through the application.

For example if the landing URL is https://example.com/apparel/men.htm and I navigate to the URL (in SPA mode) to https://example.com/apparel/kids.htm then the browser share feature will try to share the URL https://example.com/apparel/men.htm

Please note I'm not trying to use the JavaScript Web Share API. This share feature is the one in the browser menu.

[image]

Comment: I can confirm this. Just tested it with other android browsers (duckduckgo and firefox), they update the URL when navigating my SPA.

Comment: I just tested if updating the OpenGraph tags on supplemental page loads would solve this  issue for chrome on android – it doesn't.